# "Saltando por el arreglo (reload)" Omegaup

Tags: c

estoy recién empezando a programar en c y me tope con este problema, el caso es que me da 93.75/100, sinceramente ya hice de todo y no se en que caso falla.

**Descripción**

Dado un arreglo de N enteros, comienzas parado en la posición 0 y quieres llegar a la posición N - 1. A cada paso puedes ver el entero que está en la posición en la que estás parado y dar un salto de esa longitud (hacia la derecha si es positivo y hacia la izquierda si es negativo). ¿En cuántos saltos llegarás a la posición N - 1?

**Entrada**

Un entero N seguido de N enteros. Puedes suponer que 1 < N < 1000.

**Salida**

Un entero que sea el número de saltos necesarios para llegar a la posición N - 1 o el valor -1 si esto es imposible.

**Ejemplo**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n, i=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int vec[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&vec[i]);
    }
    int cont=0;
    if(vec[0]<0 || vec[0]==0 || vec[0]>n){
        printf("-1");
    }
    else
    {
        while(i!=n-1)
        {
            i=i+vec[i];
            if(i>n){
                cont=-1;
                break;
            }
            if(cont==500)
            {
                cont=-1;
                break;
            }
            cont++;
        }
        printf("%d",cont);
        
    

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: N=1000 e ingresas mil 1, que pasa?

Comment: Perdón 1000 no se puede, pero N=999 y puros 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No necesitas usar un bucle `while` para lograr lo que necesitas. La verificación del valor de la posición inicial la podrías hacer dentro del bucle, ya que si ocurre algo de ello dentro del mismo no lo estarías capturando de forma apropiada o, si lo haces, estarías repitiendo código innecesariamente.

Trata de usar nombre de variables que signifiquen algo, de esta forma es mucho más fácil entender lo que sucede.

Por ejemplo, el siguiente código, derivado del tuyo funciona de forma correcta:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n, i=0;
    // solicitamos la cantidad de elementos a almacenar
    scanf("%d",&n);

    // creamos el arreglo de valores acorde al tamaño especificado
    int values[n];

    // solicitamos 1 a 1 los valores del arreglo
    for(i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        scanf("%d",&values[i]);
    }

    int current_pos = 0;
    int jumps = -1;

    // damos un máximo de n saltos    
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
      int jump_to = values[current_pos];
      current_pos += jump_to;
      if(current_pos <= 0 || current_pos >= n) {
        break;
      }
      if(current_pos == n - 1) {
        jumps = i + 1;
        break;
      }
    }
    
    printf("\n\n%d\n", jumps);
    return 0;
}
```

Como se observa en el código, he establecido una variable llamada `jumps` que refleja la cantidad de saltos necesarios para llegar a la posición `n-1`. El arreglo de valores se recorre dando saltos y no usando el índice del iterador. Al iterar entre los valores de la longitud máxima del arreglo, garantizo que no haré iteraciones adicionales, es decir si al saltar `n` veces dentro del arreglo, no he logrado llegar a la posición `n-1` entonces es imposible llegar.

La variable `jumps` sólo se actualiza si se ha llegado a la posición `n-1`, y toma el valor del iterando actual (`i`) más uno, esto refleja la cantidad de saltos dados para alcanzar esta posición.

Como observas he tomado precaución de usar nombres de variables coherentes:

- `current_pos`: almacena el índice de la posición actual
- `jump_to`: almacena el valor del arreglo en la posición actual
- `jumps`: almacena la cantidad de salto necesarios para llegar a `n-1` o -1 si no se puede.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.